# How to know which network path my program is using?

Tags: networking, solaris, routes, packet-sniffers

How to know which network path my program is using ?

I have a program running on solaris, this machine has multiple network interfaces few connected to 1Gig and few 10 gig. Suppose my application with PID P is running. IS there any command which display which network interface my program is submitting packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Your program is delegating to the kernel the task to choose which network interface(s) to use. If there is no ambiguity, i.e. if only one interface is suitable for the job, you can then identify it.

To get what IP addresses your program is connected to, you can use this command:

`pfile`*pid*`| grep AF_INET`

`ifconfig -a` and `netstat -rn` will help knowing what interfaces are there and what routes use what interfaces.

Comment: pfilepid| grep AF_INET gives IP which the progam is connected to, though this destination IP can be routed through different network interface. Example there are two network interface one is 1 gig and 2nd one is 10 gig line. How do i test if it is going thru 1 gig or 10 gig lines ? Is there a tool or sniffer or snoop ?

Comment: You certainly can snoop the traffic and analyze how the load is balanced in such case.

Comment: Thanks. How do i ensure that i should use only 1 network interface say to listen the data ? And after doing that how do i test that it is using only one network interface? Can you give examples ?

Comment: I would suggest you to ask this as a new question.